# how to redirect static folder to wordpress page?

Tags: htaccess

I have wordpress installed, but under the root directory of my website I also have several folders used to store documents not uploaded through wordpress (e.g. pdf files of articles written by certain authors). I also have wordpress pages set to the same location. For example:

```
website.com/author1/
```

I have a wordpress page with the url `/author1/` for the author's bio. I also have numerous articles in wordpress like so: `/author-1/article1`. I also have a folder `/author1/` filled with PDFs of the author's articles.

I do this so that when someone is searching google they can search `yadda yadda site:website.com/author1/` they get results for the bio and all articles whether html or pdf.

I've been using the following code in my htaccess file to cause the bio page to load rather than the standard directory for a folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /author1/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /author2/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /author3/$ 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But the problem is that wordpress continues to overwrite this when updating the htaccess.

How can I accomplish the same function without using the htaccess file? Or, is there a way to stop at least this portion of the htaccess file from being overwritten?